# Not getting to the index.jsp page in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, indexing

When I go to http://localhost:8080/ for my spring boot form it just gives me a whitelabel error page. This is my Controller code

```
package net.codejava;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class MvcController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("Going home...");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

and here's my index.jsp code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Volunteer Management Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Volunteer Management Form</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I cannot work out why it won't show I do however get "Going home..." printed in the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think that you have problem with the view resolver add this to your application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

and move your index.jsp to /WEB-INF/jsp/

the second method is to set resolver by using WebConfig class like that :
add this class to your source package :

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("net.codejava")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new 
    InternalResourceViewResolver();
    bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
    bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return bean;
   }

}
```

update 16/03/2022
there is some problems with the the newer versions of Spring boot so we should add this been also like the following :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> 
enableDefaultServlet() {
    return (factory) -> factory.setRegisterDefaultServlet(true);
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new 
    InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void 
configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer 
configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked! I don't fully understand why as all i changed was the name of the folder that index.jsp was in and the path to it in application.properties. Originally I had the path as `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/` and the folder as view but changing it to jsp worked thank you so much

Comment: can you plz upvote my answer to unlock my account

Comment: @BenSosteric doesn't have enough rep to up vote right now. +1 from me but, ideally, you should use the same `prefix` path in both the examples, and calling `setViewClass()` is not required any more as `JstlView` is already the *default view class* in recent versions of Spring (if a JSTL jar is found on the classpath).

Comment: I had this same error after moving from `spring-boot-starter-parent 1.2.5-RELEASE` to version 2.6.3. Spring changed the property names for the newer version. The old property names were `spring.view.prefix` and `spring.view.suffix`. The new ones are have an `mvc` prefix as described above by @NTIC TECH. I've found a number of breaking changes moving to `SpringBoot` 2.x...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how did you setup JSP on spring boot because there's some specific dependencies that you need to have. Also, people nowadays use Thymeleaf or Freemarker for templating instead of JSP on spring boot. I was able to follow and run the github project from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jsp with these urls

- http://localhost:8080/spring-boot-jsp/book/viewBooks
- http://localhost:8080/spring-boot-jsp/book/addBook

Comment: I'm meant to use spring boot its for a University project where i have to make a form in spring boot with JSP but I was following a tutorial I'll go back and redo the JSP file and see if that'll fix it